# MIDIUtil crescendo: Python

Tags: python, midi

I would like to have a crescendo (rise in volume) through each note using MIDIUtil. Is there a way to do this? I have the simple MIDIUtil demo code and have modified it so each note lasts 5 beats. I have a basic code like this:

```
from midiutil.MidiFile import *
degrees  = [60, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 71, 72]
track    = 0
channel  = 0
time     = 0
duration = 5
tempo    = 120
volume   = 100
MyMIDI = MIDIFile(1)
MyMIDI.addTempo(track,time, tempo)
for pitch in degrees:
    MyMIDI.addNote(track, channel, pitch, time, duration, volume)
    time = time + 1
with open("major-scale.mid", "wb") as output_file:
    MyMIDI.writeFile(output_file)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You have a `volume` variable, you can start with the lowest value (0, I assume) and increase it until it reaches the maximum value inside the `for` loop (something like `if volume < 100: volume += increase_per_note` - obviously, define `increase_per_note` before the loop). Does that work?

Comment: Crescendo of velocity or crescendo of volume (no they are not the same)?

Comment: Does "through each note" mean that each note should have a different volume, or that the volume should change while a single note is playing?

Comment: "Through note" means that would it be possible for the volume of ONE note to increase during it's duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the velocity of each note by increasing the value of the `volume` parameter. Something like this:

```
from midiutil.MidiFile import *
degrees  = [60, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 71, 72]
track    = 0
channel  = 0
time     = 0
duration = 4
tempo    = 120
volume   = 15
MyMIDI = MIDIFile(1)
MyMIDI.addTempo(track,time, tempo)
for pitch in degrees:
    MyMIDI.addNote(track, channel, pitch, time, duration, volume)
    time = time + 4
    volume = volume + 15
with open("major-scale.mid", "wb") as output_file:
    MyMIDI.writeFile(output_file)
```

This will make each note have a higher velocity than the previous, but the volume will not increase while the note is sounding. (Also note that I changed duration to 4 and increase `time` by 4 for each note. This makes each note a whole note with no overlap. With your example, each note is five beats long and starts one beat after the previous note, causing a lot of overlap.)

Calling this parameter `volume` is a mistake on the part of the implementor of MIDIUtil. It should be called "velocity". Volume is a completely different thing in MIDI. Volume is continuous controller #7 and affects the volume of everything sounding on that MIDI channel. Velocity is the strength at which an individual note is struck. There's not even any guarantee that velocity will affect the volume of a note. It's common, but a sound can be programmed so that velocity affects any aspect of the sound, not just loudness.

Here's a similar program that uses the volume continuous controller to increase the volume while each note (all with velocity 80) is sounding. (It's not elegant code. I'm not much of a Python programmer and it's past my bedtime.)

```
from midiutil.MidiFile import *
degrees  = [60, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 71, 72]
track    = 0
channel  = 0
time     = 0
duration = 4
tempo    = 120
volume   = 8
MyMIDI = MIDIFile(1)
MyMIDI.addTempo(track, time, tempo)
for pitch in degrees:
    MyMIDI.addNote(track, channel, pitch, time, duration, 80)
    for i in range (0, 15):
        MyMIDI.addControllerEvent(track, channel, time + i * 4 / 15, 7, volume)
        volume = volume + 1
    time = time + 4
with open("major-scale-with-volume.mid", "wb") as output_file:
    MyMIDI.writeFile(output_file)
```

Here's what the first few measures look like:

[image: Event list]

Comment: What software did you use to analyze the MIDI-file content?

Comment: @PhilipBergström That's the event list window in Logic Pro.